# Force forward slash to // instead of automatically combine to / in string

Tags: android, uri, filenotfoundexception, universal-image-loader

Currently, I used Image Loader Universal library to load files from File path in sdcard.

I get issue with forward slash in Uri from File Path.

The correct string to load file is this one : `content://media/external/images/media/24415`

But when I put as these codes :

```
imageLoader.displayImage(
                Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(FILE_PATH)).toString(),
                // .replace("%3A", "/" + java.io.File.separator),
                markableImageView, mDio,
                new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        if (loadedImage != null & view != null) {
                            ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                    loadedImage,
                                    mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.width_file_view),
                                    mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.height_file_view),
                                    false));
                        }
                    }
                }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressUpdate(
                            String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                    }
                });
    }
```

It automatically combine 2 forward slashes `//` to 1 forward slash `/` (it means `content:/media/external/images/media/24415`), so the Uri is not correct for library can read file, `FileNotFoundException` occured.

It is not I want, what I want is still keep `//`, not combined to `/` (it means `content://media/external/images/media/24415`)

People who know,

please help me, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I get is `combine from // to / in string`. So now there are ways to avoid like :

1 - Split the string as following codes :

```
// Should load file from sd card by parsing Uri
    String FILE_PATH = mAlAlbumItem.get(pos).getFilePath();

    // content://media/external/images/media/24415

    String[] SPLIT = FILE_PATH.split("//");

    if (FILE_PATH != null) {
        // Display image

        /**
         * Should use separate string to void wrap these words "//" to "/"
         */
        try {
            Enterprise.imageLoader.displayImage(
                    SPLIT[0] + "//" + SPLIT[1],
                    markableImageView, mDio,
                    new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            if (loadedImage != null & view != null) {
                                ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                        loadedImage,
                                        mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.width_file_view),
                                        mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.height_file_view),
                                        false));
                            }
                        }
                    }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressUpdate(
                                String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                        }
                    });
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2 - Parse Uri by using `Scheme.FILE.wrap(FILE_PATH)` or `Scheme.FILE.wrap(new File(FILE_PATH).getAbsolutePath())` instead of `Uri.fromFile(new File(FILE_PATH))`